# Are VS static strings writable?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, static-variables

If I declare the following static variable in a function:

```
void some_function()
{
    static char name[] = " :\\Folder\\file.ext";

    name[0] = 'C';
}
```

Can I write into it, or do I have to declare it on the stack for that?

PS. This code may be compiled with Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 and up.

Comment: `static char name[] = "blah";` is writable, but `static char* name = "blah";` is not writable, and should be `static char const*` (compilers will likely complain if it isn't).

Comment: @Eljay: Hah, interesting. I didn't know that. Thanks for the info. The linker indeed places it in the read-only memory section if it's declared as `static char* name`. Must be intrinsically implying it as a `const`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Static objects in C++ follow the same general rules as any other objects: they are writable as long as they are not `const`. Elements of your `name` array are writable.

And there's nothing special about VS in this regard.

Comment: OK. Thanks. I was just confirming.

Answer (score 0):

You can write to `static` variables. Note, however, that a `static` variable  is initialized only once at program start. So if you enter the function a second time, content of `name` will then be `"C:\\Folder\\file.ext"` from the start of the function on.

Try:

```
void some_function()
{
    static char name[] = " :\\Folder\\file.ext";

    cout << name  << endl;
    name[0] = 'C';
}

int main()
{
    some_function();
    some_function();
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
 :\Folder\file.ext
C:\Folder\file.ext
```

Comment: That was the whole point of me using a static string. No wasted time to push it on the stack if it wasn't static.